# What does the count on the Chromium Launcher Icon tell?

Tags: unity, launcher, chromium

On my Chromium Launcher Icon a count of 4 is displayed. I have two Chromium windows with several tabs open.

[image]

A count with progress bar was always displayed when downloading. Therefore I checked this first but there is no download going on in any of my open tabs, and other than with downloads there is no progress bar now.

Here is 12.04 LTS amd64 running updated Chromium 23.0.1271.97 (precise-updates).

What would be the purpose of this count on the Launcher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counter for Chromium relates to file downloads in progress or pending.

Selecting *"Tools --> Download"* or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> opens `chrome://downloads` in a new tab and this allows you to view your download history (and also to clear it).

There are rare instances when a download waits for user approval but the message asking for confirmation was not displayed (e.g. when a script was called on a website to open a new window but closes this window again before we had a chance to see or approve a message).

The counter then helps us to see that downloads are pending. These can then  also be managed from the download history:

[image]

Comment: That is odd cause that is what the badges are for I believe as far as browsers go, cause I have opened multiple tabs and even multiple windows and have not been able to recreate that..other than when downloading files.

Comment: Could be a bug maybe

Comment: Well since there were PDF's waiting for approval I wouldn't consider it a bug.

Comment: @vasa1, thanks for the edit advice, I didn't even think about it..